# Using I Can't Believe It's Not Butter and salt in a recipe that calls for unsalted butter

Tags: cookies, salt, butter, recipe-scaling, margarine

There's a cookie recipe I'm going to make that calls for **3/4 cup unsalted butter**, melted and **1/2 teaspoon salt**. We use I Can't Believe It's Not Butter as a substitute for butter, however that contains some Sodium already. So to figure out how much I should reduce the salt by I did the following:

- ICBINB contains 55mg of Sodium per 2 tsp
- That means for 3/4 cups = 36 tsp = 2*18 tsp, there is 0.055*18 mg
  or about 1 gram of Sodium in ICBINB
- This next step I am not sure about. Using Google, it tells me 1/2
  tsp of salt (or 2.5 grams of salt) contains 1000 mg of Sodium. Is
  this correct?

If the above is correct, that means 3/4 cup of ICBINB contains 1/2 teaspoon of salt, and since the recipe calls for 1/2 tsp salt with 3/4 cup of unsalted butter, does this mean I put no salt in the recipe since ICBIB already contains the necessary salt? Or should I put a tiny pinch of salt anyway just in case?

Comment: It sounds like you've done this before, but just in case... cookies can be sensitive, and replacing butter with margarine can definitely make them come out a bit differently.

Comment: Just a note, this may not be a good substitute, depending on which ICBINB product you are using and the type of recipe you are making.

Comment: We do also have vegetable oil, extra virgin olive oil, and clarified butter in the house. Would any of those be better substitutes or should I stick with margarine?

Comment: Melted (but not clarified) butter would also have a little bit of water in it.  I don't know if the substitute would as well or just be whipped fat (and salt and flavorings).  The water might be needed for gluten development if you're trying to get a chewy cookie.

Comment: Are these cookies going to be baked? Maybe you should start a new question that includes the recipe & instructions, asking if this would be a good substitution?

Comment: Related question about substituting butter in cookies: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/52354/substituting-margarine-for-butter-in-cookies Not sure about the answers but it's worth having a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math and numbers look about right. I found 1/2 tsp. table salt is 3 grams, so about 1125 mg sodium. I would not add any additional salt in this recipe.

Comment: Was that for table salt, or kosher salt?  They pack differently, so there's less sodium (as it's less weight) in the same measure of kosher salt vs. table salt.

Comment: @Joe - Table salt. Kosher, pickling and other specialty salts will not have the same weight/volume ratio.